# Can you declare a object literal type that allows unknown properties in typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript2.0, object-literal

Essentially I want to ensure that an object argument contains all of the required properties, but can contain any other properties it wants.  For example:

```
function foo(bar: { baz: number }) : number {
    return bar.baz;
}

foo({ baz: 1, other: 2 });
```

But this results in:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'other' does not exist in type '{ baz: number; }'.
```

Comment: There is also a `suppressExcessPropertyErrors` prop. Using this prop you can disable reporting of excess property errors during the creation of object literals.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, i hate answering my own questions, but the other answers inspired a little thought...  This works:

```
function foo<T extends { baz: number }>(bar: T): void {
    console.log(bar.baz);
}

foo({baz: 1, other: 2});
```

Comment: This looks like you have set it up so the function takes a type argument but you don't give it a type argument. Do you mind explaining a bit what you are doing here? Thank you.

Comment: He's letting TS infer the type argument automatically based on the value passed to the bar parameter.

Comment: Applications where the extra properties should affect the return type or otherwise be tracked, this is the most correct solution.

Comment: This is the only real solution

Answer (score 130):

Yes, you can. Try this:

```
interface IBaz {
    baz: number;
    [key: string]: any;
}

function foo(bar: IBaz) : number {
    return bar.baz;
}

foo({ baz: 1, other: 2 });
```

Comment: I was initially thinking this, but wanted inline...  (and for some reason i screwed up the [key: string] part using parens instead of square brackets)...

Comment: You don't have to use an `any` you just have to make sure to include an `| number` (in this example) or you'll get a TS error on the `baz: number;`. Or you can use `unknown`

Answer (score 16):

If the known fields are coming from a generic type the way to allow wildcards is with `T & {[key: string]: unknown}`, any fields that are known must fit with the type's constraints and other fields are allowed (and considered type `unknown`)

Here is a sample:

```
type WithWildcards<T> = T & { [key: string]: unknown };

function test(foo: WithWildcards<{baz: number}>) {}

test({ baz: 1 }); // works
test({ baz: 1, other: 4 }); // works
test({ baz: '', other: 4 }); // fails since baz isn't a number
```

Then if you have a generic type `T` you can allow wildcard fields with `WithWildCards<T>`

Note that extra properties are not marked as errors if the object is coming from anything other than an object literal, TS is just telling you that with the typing putting that property in the literal is extraneous.

[Here are some other cases where extra properties are and aren't allowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=16&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GcDeBYAKGWTgH4AuZLMKUAc0OICMKqb7CBfQsATwAcUAdWBgAFiIA2AEwRwo0rAB4AKgD5kAXmQrkAMmQ5kAbQDWEXpWq0QdALqUAriFMh0AdxDJOAbkKFpCARJeRQYZwQwYHQvRCR+MAxsAAoYTEokrABKSgA3dGBpPwJA4NDkcJBI6NiEeLApaVT05BFxRrkFZUy1HPzC-wI4iATM5OIcOHIAcmmAGmR0cWhKWc4s5AB6TeQAUQAlfYB5fapQJGRl5H4odEEoPmRgLGQIAA8aOBAIdEcsQgQMWoyGkcDAcC0himswWSzEK2Qa0Iw1GmCw4xBYLgG22JEkkg8EGkZyqKFETxegIAtvwwcAmJIIAs+IIsAhaAkQegIFgQNMwBV0FALrxfpd0MgoBAqehcigrjc7tAojyAUCBW4wABhdA0sGQnBwhFIoZ1EaJNHJTU6vVgHGbA7HfaUFQCFDTIxGqBWdi2HzeabIMRwF5ua63e4ql6gZDUmVedyiMSXN2IzLTZFm1EpSYzebIAB0RetutpYHWWx24meFLxWAlcHxhOJmfqjStSxtZfteIJ7iJQA)

```
interface Foos{
  a?: string
  b?: string
}
type WithWildcards<T> = T & { [key: string]: unknown };

declare function acceptFoos(foo: Foos): void;
declare function acceptWild(foo: WithWildcards<Foos>):void

acceptFoos(  {a:'', other: ''}) // ERROR since the property is extraneous
const data = {a:'', other: ''}
acceptFoos(  data) // allowed since it is compatible, typescript doesn't force you to remove the properties
const notCompat = {other: ''}
acceptFoos(notCompat) //ERROR: Type '{ other: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'Foos'
acceptFoos({a:'', ...notCompat}) // this is also allowed 
acceptWild(notCompat) // allowed
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to allow unknown properties for the entire object, you can use `Record`

```
function doStuff(payload: Record<string|number, unknown>): Record<string|number, unknown> {
  return { anyProp: 'anyValue' }
}
```

Comment: Using `record` made it clean and clear 

Answer (score 3):

This can be most easily accomplished by defining a type definition for the the function parameter. Here's an example with inline type definition:

```
function foo(bar: { baz: number }) : number {
    return bar.baz;
}

const obj = { baz: 1, other: 2 };

foo(obj);
```

Comment: this one seems to result in another msg that is like this:
Type ... has no properties in common with type '...'p
using typescript 2.3.4

Comment: How does this work? If you put the object inline it doesn't work.

Comment: It's an inline type definition, not an inline object. Runs fine in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAjAhgJwFyIDei2AXgWCALYYCmOiAvgJSIXV0OEBQifiOWlBA4k2HADoyAbm6Nu3CAgDOURHAwArRAF4iJLOUQBGADTqoAC3oEATE1mKVcADa0JLuAHM0KdBs1mZmkgA).

Answer (score 0):

When working with `unknown` type you can use the concept of `narrowing` to check out for the type you expect to get from the value you are going through and manipulate the values as per your need
E.g

```
const messages: string []=Object.values(obj).map(val: unknown=>typeof obj==='object'?obj!['message']:obj)
```