# Typescript how to type the rest of parameters in object

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  function test(data){
      console.log(data)
  }

  test({comments: 'hi', eat: true, sleep: true})
```

In the test function, I am sure of the comment argument will appear, where as for other arguments, the properties might be dynamic but the value will be of boolean type,

```
  test({comments: 'hi', drink: true, sleep: true})
```

considering this situation, how should I correctly type data?
I have tried something like this, but it seems wrong

```
function(data: {data: {comments: string, [key: string]: boolean})
```

Comment: Yes. i just want to console. Edited the question

Comment: Is the question, then, "what type do I give to the parameter `data`, which should be an object with at least one property named `comments` of type string, but which could have lots of other properties that I don't care about"?

Comment: Yes.. I dont care about other properties..

Comment: If you don't care about the other properties, then `type DataType = { comments: string; [key: string]: unknown; };` will work. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860616

Comment: Sorry about the above comment. I know that other properties value would be boolean

Comment: Ah good, then it is not the same as this question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42724170/831878 Because you want to restrict all the other properties to boolean?

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work, as soon as i keep boolean, vs code editor is throwing errors

Comment: Right, right, your question is indeed different (and pretty cool). Looks like intersection types have potential, but fall short. More info here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20597.

Comment: Relevant issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you some kind of workaround:

```
function test<T extends {
  [key: string]: any;
}>(data: { comments: unknown } & { [key in keyof T]: key extends "comments" ? string : boolean }) {
  const comments = data.comments as string;
  console.log(comments);
  console.log(data.eat);
  console.log(data.sleep);
}

test({comments: "hi"}); // works
test({comments: "hi", eat: true}); // works
test({comments: true}); // doesn't works
test({comments: 5}); // doesn't works
test({comments: "hi", eat: "true"}); // doesn't works
test({comments: "hi", eat: 5}); // doesn't works
```

It typed well outside of the function's body, but in function's body to type `data.comments` correctly you should add some narrowing.